# Drive picker in Google App Maker stopped working

Tags: google-app-maker

I am using Drive Picker widget in my app maker application. It was working fine before but suddenly it has stopped working/ working intermittently.

On clicking the drive picker widget a blank screen opens up and I see below error in the browser console.

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin
>   provided ('https://docs.google.com') does not match the recipient
>   window's origin
>   ('https://n-yx2zaueilofy7fq447wkpjrsjaoo5ymoirri23i-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com').

To confirm that it is not specific to my application I tried the same in Drive Picker Sample application from appmaker samples and got the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: The error you are referring to is normal, it won't affect the drive picker behavior. Try restarting your computer and see if that works. Unless there is something else that you are not describing, nothing should be wrong.

Comment: Looks like it is something related to my network restrictions. With my home network it is working properly